# Android - Transparent ToggleButton on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-relativelayout, togglebutton

I have a very simple layout: RelativeLayout with a MapView and a ToggleButton. Why is the ToggleButton showing up transparent when I didn't specify it should anywhere, and the real question, how can I make it stop?

[image: Transparent ToggleButton]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="NoYouCantSeeMyKey" />

<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/aerialsbutton"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:textOn="Aerials On"
    android:textOff="Aerials Off"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried setting alpha to 1 and switching the order of MapView and ToggleButton with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: I have my Applcation theme set to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"`. Could that matter?

UPDATE 2: The theme makes no difference. Pretty stumped here.

Comment: Have you tried 
android:disabledAlpha
attribute?

Comment: It didn't help, and shouldn't because my ToggleButton isn't disabled.

Comment: you can give setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable d)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What would I set it to? I just want the stock ToggleButton, without transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a theme or a style applied to it which is defined somewhere else. That's not a default toggle button style. Here's a portion of a screen capture of a nearly identical xml in a test project of mine - this shows the default toggle button:

[image]

I hope this is of some use.

Comment: Thank you, what theme/style did you apply to your Togglebutton in the screenshot? I just want the Honeycomb default, which I thought was Holo.

Comment: I didn't apply any theme at all. I've just tried the app on an API 11 (Honeycomb) emulator and the button looks the same as my screen shot.

Comment: So I just created a new app on API 11 with matching emulator version, with no style or theme set anywhere, and the ToggleButton is still transparent on the map. Can you possibly share your code with me so I can reproduce how you got the non-transparent button?

Comment: Marking as answered, because I suspect my dev environment is the culprit here and your answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just adding style to ToggleButton tag:

```
 <ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/my_toggle_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="@string/toggle_button_on"
    android:textOff="@string/toggle_button_off"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Toggle"/>
```

I hope this helps somebody with the same problem. :-)